# Django Rest Framework not passing 'X_USERNAME' on request - authenticate method param

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to set a Custom Authentication class on Django Rest Framework, but all client requests return the same error:

{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

So, debugging the Custom class and printing the request.META atributte it has no 
X_USERNAME key.

CustomAuth class:

```
 class TecnicoAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):

 def authenticate(self, request):
    username = request.META.get('X_USERNAME')
    if not username:
        return None
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')
    return (user,None)
```

on settings.py file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : (
            'os_hotlink.auth.TecnicoAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
```

}

on apache config file:

```
 WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

And finally the request method using httpie:

```
http -a user:pass http://127.0.0.1/
```

Comment: the request method with httpie is incorrect, that is for basic authentication, you have created a custom authentication class, and it is looking for a custom request header called X_username

Answer (score 2):

It is looking for a custom request header named 'X_USERNAME'.

So you need to define the user in a custom request header called X_USERNAME in your HTTpie request...

I think that if you have the username 'user' then you should try sending it as this:

http 127.0.0.1 X_USERNAME:user

HTTP headers

To set custom headers you can use the Header:Value notation:

```
$ http example.org  User-Agent:PoopyPants  'Cookie:valued-visitor=yes;whatever=whatever;etc=etc'  \
    X_USERNAME:user  Referer:http://stackoverflow.com/


GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: valued-visitor=yes;whatever=whatever;etc=etc
Host: 127.0.0.1
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/
User-Agent: PoopyPants
X_USERNAME: user
```

Comment: X_USERNAME is a http header attribute passed through wsgi and captured by drf api

Comment: But on this case, i cannot capture the attribute for any reason.

Comment: Yes my conclusion would be that it's not passing the header?

Comment: that is exactly my trouble

Comment: are you on apache?

Comment: yes, a set the WSGIPassAuthorization option on configuration file

Comment: and is mod_wsgi in the apachi config also?

Comment: yes, mod_wsgi on apache and WSGIPassAuthorization setted

Comment: I just noticed you put your HTTPie call up there.  your custom authentication field is looking for a custom request header named 'X_USERNAME'. you need to modify that